# Regular Expression for numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I need a little help for finding regular expression that suits my need, what I want is that may the input be any string, the regular expression finds any and all integer values and returns them, say

```
string s1 = "This is some string"
string s2 = " this is 2 string"
string s3 = " this is 03 string"
string s4 = "4 this is the 4th string"
string s5 = "some random string: sakdflajdf;la  989230"
string s6 = "3494309 !@# 234234"
```

Now what I want is for the regular expression to return,

```
for s1 = return null (// nothing)
s2 = return 2
s3 = return 0 and 3 (// may separately as 0 and 3 or together as 03 doesn't matter)
s4 = return 4 and 4 (// it has 4 2 times right?)
s5 = 989230 (// may together as this or separately as 9 8 9 2 3 0 again is unimportant, but what's important is that it should return all integer values)
s6 = 3494309 and 234234 (// again may they be together as this or like this 3 4 9 4 3 0 9 and 2 3 4 2 3 4 that is unimportant, all that is imp is that it should return all integers)
```

I have tried `[0-9]`, `\d` and `^.*[0-9]+.*$`, but none of them seemed to work. Can anyone please help?

ps : please see the updated question at [Rename file using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117237/rename-file-using-regular-expression)

Comment: How are you applying the expression? Please post your code. Also please clarify what you mean with *but none of them seemed to work*. What exactly does not work? What is the result you get? `\d` only matches a single digit, `^.*[0-9]+.*$` matches the whole string if it contains at least on digit. It appears you want `\d+`.

Comment: The answers below will find the numbers in your input. It is up to you to write a method that returns the values you want given a certain number. I suggest using a switch statement.

Comment: please see the update question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117237/rename-file-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regular expression that will match one or more numerals in succession is:

```
\d+
```

You could apply it this way:

```
Regex.Matches(myString, @"\d+")
```

Which will return a collection of [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) object. This will contain the matched values.

You could use it like so:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, @"\d+");

if (matches.Count == 0)
  return null;

var nums = new List<int>();
foreach(var match in matches)
{
  nums.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));
}

return nums;
```

Comment: To get them all separate just use `\d`.

Comment: @Razort4x: The problem is that there is not a lot information in your question, so we make can only make a guess.

Comment: @Razort4x - I did. A shame you didn't explain _where_ you are stuck and _why_ these regular expressions don't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know it seems a little facile but I think `\d` will do what you want

I know you stated you tried this ... one thing to be careful of is if you are using a string to denote this you need to ignore escapes

```
var pattern = @"\d+";
```